# Transpose rows to column

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

currently, I am trying to transpose my data to the column but I am unable to achieve the desired result.

Given is my data in database table:

```
 DECLARE @mytable TABLE (
[Type_ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ModelID] [int] NOT NULL,
[MotorTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
[VoltageTypeID] [int] NOT NULL,
[MotorAmps] [decimal](18, 5) NULL
)

insert into @mytable
 values
(10,    4,  1,  2.40000),
(10,    4,  2,  1.20000),
(10,    2,  1,  1.80000),
(10,    2,  2,  0.90000),
(10,    1,  3,  1.80000)
```

The desired result is required:

```
    |VoltageTypeID  |1   | 2    |3   |4   | 
    |1              |Null|1.8   |Null|2.4 |
    |2              |Null|0.9   |Null|1.2 |
    |3              |1.8 |Null  |Null|Null|
```

where 1,2, 3, 4 is MotorType and values in these columns are amps.

I have tried to do this with the pivot but unable to achieve

Comment: could you pls add a minimal example (at least a `create table` and some `insert`s that make reproduction a little easier)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use [**PIVOT**](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) operator:

```
    SELECT
    VoltageTypeID
    ,CAST([1] as decimal(18,1)) AS [1]
    ,CAST([2] as decimal(18,1)) AS [2]
    ,CAST([3] as decimal(18,1)) AS [3]
    ,CAST([4] as decimal(18,1)) AS [4]
FROM (
    SELECT
        VoltageTypeID
        ,motorTypeID
        ,MotorAmps
    FROM @mytable
) tbl
PIVOT(
    MAX(MotorAmps) FOR motorTypeID IN ([1], [2], [3], [4])
)pvt
```

**Output**:

```
+---------------+------+------+------+------+
| VoltageTypeID |  1   |  2   |  3   |  4   |
+---------------+------+------+------+------+
|             1 | NULL | 1,8  | NULL | 2,4  |
|             2 | NULL | 0,9  | NULL | 1,2  |
|             3 | 1,8  | NULL | NULL | NULL |
+---------------+------+------+------+------+
```

Comment: I have already achieved this. I need to group by with the VoltageTypeID as well. This is what I need to achieve
 |VoltageTypeID  |1   | 2    |3   |4   | 
    |1              |Null|1.8   |Null|2.4 |
    |2              |Null|0.9   |Null|1.2 |
    |3              |1.8 |Null  |Null|Null|

Comment: @Asad i have updated the answer with the output ... It's the same

Comment: It does not produce the same output for me.

Comment: @Asad how about now?